# SQL filtrar por fecha con actualización en automatico

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Necesito saber como puedo filtrar los valores totales desde el año pasado 2018-01-01 hasta el último día del mes pasado, ósea si actualmente es el mes de abril necesito hasta el 2020-03-31

la tabla que tengo es así:

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

el código que tengo es manual, que yo especifico la fecha de inicio y fin, pero la fecha final varia deacuerdo al tiempo, y aquí está la pregunta qué modifico para que la fecha final en automatico:

```
SELECT SUM(venta.total_venta) AS total_venta 
FROM venta 
WHERE fecha_hora BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2020-03-31' 
AND venta.estado='PENDIENTE'
```

En vez de poner esto

```
BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2020-03-31'
```

Que el cambio lo haga sólo en la fecha final, dado que la primera no varia nunca

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: La fecha final sera cada dia ? puedes utilizar la fecha del sistema... o tu envias la fecha final ??? , no entiendo bien lo que deseas hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías probar usando

```
LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Lo que hace **[last_day](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-last_day-function.php)**, es que obtiene el último día del mes que le pasas como parámetro - que en este caso sería el mes en curso (**[now()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_now.asp)**) -, y le restas un mes a dicho período

De esta forma tu consulta quedaría así

```
SELECT SUM(venta.total_venta) AS total_venta 
FROM venta 
WHERE fecha_hora BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND LAST_DAY(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
AND venta.estado='PENDIENTE'
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas :)

Comment: dudoso.. si febrero tiene 28 te lleva al 31 de enero o al 28?

Comment: Debería enviarte al 31 de enero si la consulta la realizas en febrero no? Creo que no hace distinción si el mes tiene menos días o es bisiesto. De todas formas lo corroboro ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias @PauloUrbanoRivera eso era ya quedo, gracias de verad